# Frustrated classical field theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, ising-model, classical-field-theory, spin-models

The frustrated Ising model (see e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/435952/226902)) is an example of a system that shows no unique ground state and many metastable states (its "energy landscape" is extremely complex). Frustration comes from the fact that the product of the coupling constants around a "plaquette" of the graph is negative (see e.g. the Wiki article ["geometrical frustration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_frustration)).

This is quite clear, but I was wondering if there are **continuous** systems (as opposed to the Ising paradigm, that is a model on a graph) showing frustration. *Are you aware of any **examples** that can be found in the statistical field theory literature?*

An example, just to be concrete: we may imagine a model for a mixture of two substances, where the two densities fields (treated as scalar fields $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in the spatial continuum with local interactions of the kind $\phi_1^a \phi_2^b$ for $a,b>0$) interact in such a way that they naturally tend to cluster and separate into blobs, similarly to what happens in the [Cahn–Hilliard model for a binary fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation). Is there a notion of frustration for such "simple" two-field theories? How to define this notion (if any)?

Comment: It is not clear how the notion *product of coupling constants is negative* can be made continuous. Parhaps [anyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon) and fractional Hall effect could be made somehow fit this definition. Or vortices?

Comment: Dear @RogerVadim, I agree (I am not proposing that the notion is exactly the same, I think it should be something totally different... I was thinking if the Wilson loop contains info about the "frustration" of the model, but for that you need a theory with gauge fields as far as I know). An alternative would be to put the field theory on a cubic lattice (because the cubic is symmetric enough that you recover the full rotation group in the continuum). Just speculations though...

Comment: I am not familiar with fluid models. But for frustrated spin models such as the Ising spin-glass, there are several known barriers to constructing a consistent field theory in the continuum limit. One such obstruction is the fact that doing RG may result in chaotic orbits (meaning that the limiting field theory may not exist). See https://nyuscholars.nyu.edu/en/publications/chaotic-size-dependence-in-spin-glasses